# ValueError: cannot set toolkit to wx because it has already been set to qt4

Tags: python, mayavi

The following import

```
from mayavi import mlab
```

generates the [value error](http://pastebin.com/aXCBLHuF).

I installed Mayavi using setuptools ([as described here](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/installation.html#installing-ready-made-distributions)). The gui works fine (some bugs here and there but still I can use the modules etc.) I am guessing some thing didn't went well with the install. Any suggestions how I can fix my installation(if that is what the problem is) ?

**Edit 1:**

I uninstalled mayavi and reinstalled it (using pip), but the `valueError` is still present.

**Edit 2:**

The system I have the installation on is a virtual `Ubuntu 15.04` (using VMware 6.0.6). I have pasted the [pip install mayavi output here](http://pastebin.com/JXGRVAR6).

**Edit 3:**
After reinstalling a previous version of `Mayavi : 4.3.1`, I still get the same error. I am using `Python : 2.7.9`.

Comment: What OS? What Python distribution? Where are you running your code from? (Python script in terminal, IPython terminal, Canopy GUI,....)

Comment: @JonathanMarch I do not have access to the machine I was running on at the moment, I will add the specific version in the post by tomorrow. (Ubuntu 15 on VMware fusion.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a post on SO :

[How to get MayaVi2 to default to/use Qt rather than wx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350884/how-to-get-mayavi2-to-default-to-use-qt-rather-than-wx)

where it shows how you can set qt4, without having to uninstall wxPython (as the other answer suggests) :

```
export ETS_TOOLKIT=qt4
```

I found out about it among the issues section on the Mayavi github : [Issue 265](http://github.com/enthought/mayavi/issues/265)

Answer (score 2):

Don't know, whether my answer is relevant now, but this helped me:
I have PyQt4 on my machine, but I've installed wxPython for Mayavi, so they were conflicting. I've removed wxPython and now it works just perfect.

Comment: Your answer is correct. There is a post however on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350884/how-to-get-mayavi2-to-default-to-use-qt-rather-than-wx where you can do this without uninstalling : `export ETS_TOOLKIT=qt4` . I found out about it on the Mayavi github : https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/issues/265

Answer (score 0):

Dude, maybe you made the same silly mistake as I did, **LOL**.

### Same Error

I was trying to use `WXAgg` as backend for matplotlib and traitsui but I got a `RuntimeError: Importing from wx backend after selecting qt4 backend`. The import part is as follows:

```
import matplotlib
# We want matplotlib to use a wxPython backend
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
import wx

from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from traits.api import Instance
from traitsui.wx.editor import Editor
from traitsui.wx.basic_editor_factory import BasicEditorFactory
```

Then I tried to manually change the backend with following codes:

```
from traits.etsconfig.api import ETSConfig
ETSConfig.toolkit = 'wx'
```

Guess what, I got the same `ValueError: cannot set toolkit to wx because it has already been set to qt4` as you do.

### Check Before You Go

After hours of searching and debugging, I almost gave up until suddenly I recall that I have set this variable system wide once. How stupid I am not to follow this hint and check `ETS_TOOLKIT`!

Anybody who come across this error again, pls check you system settings with `echo $ETS_TOOLKIT` on Linux or `echo %ETS_TOOLKIT%` on Windows. If it says `qt4`, then it's your fault causing this error.