# MayaVi ValueError, how to run with wx backend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, mayavi

At this point, I'm just trying to get started with using MayaVi, but can not get it to run from within Python shell/scripts. The MayaVi GUI *does* work, however.

I'm trying to run some of the examples I found online (e.g. [[1]](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_wx_embedding.html#example-wx-embedding)), however when I attempt to run them, I get the seemingly ubiquitous error (e.g. [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708292/valueerror-cannot-set-toolkit-to-wx-because-it-has-already-been-set-to-qt4), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350884/how-to-get-mayavi2-to-default-to-use-qt-rather-than-wx)) of:

```
Value Error: cannot set toolkit to wx because it has already been set to qt4
```

The solutions to the above referenced SO threads all seem to be: discard wx and use qt4.  However, I'm ultimately interested in embedding my visualizations into a wxPython application, and thus would like to use wx!

I have tried adding:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WxAgg')
```

to the beginning of the example script, but that does not solve the issue.

I am running:

- Windows 7, 64 Bit
- Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.6 (64 bit)
- wxPython 3.0.2.0
- mayavi 4.4.3
- matplotlib 1.5.1

Unsure what else (if anything) may be relevant.

Is there a solution where I can run mayavi with wx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, it's the most obvious solution.  As suggested in the referenced SO solutions, rather than setting ETS_TOOLKIT = "qt4", just need to set it to "wx".  I do this within the script (at the start) with:

```
import os
os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'wx'
```

And it works fine!